Updating ButtonStyle dynamically
I am trying to create a custom ButtonStyle which responds to changes in state. I can’t get it to update when the state changes.
Here is a simplified version:
struct TestButton: ButtonStyle {
    @State var selected: Bool = true
    func makeBody(configuration: ButtonStyleConfiguration) -> some View {
        configuration.label
            .frame(width: 48)
            .padding(EdgeInsets(top: 3, leading: 4, bottom: 3, trailing: 4))
            .background(selected ? .green : .red)
            .cornerRadius(14)
    }
}

struct TestView: View {
    @AppStorage("test") var test = 1
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            Button(test == 1 ? "Yes" : "No") { test = 1 }
                .buttonStyle(TestButton(selected: test == 1))
            Button(test == 2 ? "Yes" : "No") { test = 2 }
                .buttonStyle(TestButton(selected: test == 2))
            Button(test == 3 ? "Yes" : "No") { test = 3 }
                .buttonStyle(TestButton(selected: test == 3))
        }
//      .id(UUID())     //  trying to avoid this
        .padding()
    }
}

The variable test is set by the buttons, and I want it to change the appearance of the button. The test test == … works correctly as the text switches between Yes and No. However, when I use it with the selected parameter, it doesn’t change anything. It sets the value when the view is first loaded, but doesn’t update.
The variable in the View uses @AppStorage, but I’ve tried with @State and get the same results.
I know that I can fake it by adding .id(UUID()), but I’m not sure whether it’s the best approach.
Ho can I update the ButtonStyle?

Just define selected be a normal property. Here is an example, I just change @AppStorage to a @State to easier for testing:
struct TestButton: ButtonStyle {
    let selected: Bool
    func makeBody(configuration: ButtonStyleConfiguration) -> some View {
        configuration.label
            .frame(width: 48)
            .padding(EdgeInsets(top: 3, leading: 4, bottom: 3, trailing: 4))
            .background(selected ? .green : .red)
            .cornerRadius(14)
    }
}
    
struct TestView: View {
    @State var test = 1
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            Button(test == 1 ? "Yes" : "No") { test = 1 }
                .buttonStyle(TestButton(selected: test == 1))
            Button(test == 2 ? "Yes" : "No") { test = 2 }
                .buttonStyle(TestButton(selected: test == 2))
            Button(test == 3 ? "Yes" : "No") { test = 3 }
                .buttonStyle(TestButton(selected: test == 3))
        }
        .padding()
    }
}

When using @State var selected in ButtonStyle, It just recevie the value when a identity created, adding .id(UUID()) work because it cause current ButtonStyle to be destroy and a new Identity to be created therefore ButtonStyle will received selected change. I recommend you to watch "Demystify SwiftUI" to have more understand.


It’s not working for me. I tried changing to @State before, and tried it again now, but the button colour doesn’t change.

So when you change my example code from @State var test to @AppStorage("test"), it won't work ?

It doesn’t work either way for me.

In my example, when pressing a button, It title will become "Yes" and background turn green and other button's background will turn red and also the title will become "No", Is that what you are trying to acheive?

Ah, my mistake. I missed that first line. Just remove @State. That’s just what I was after.
